# Metric Spaces Past paper qestion

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For each $a ∈ X$ let $f_a : X → \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$f_a(x) = d(x, a)$.

(a) Prove that for all $a, b ∈ X$
$$\sup_{x∈X}|f_a(x) − f_b(x)| = d(a, b).$$

(b) Fix a point $c ∈ X$. For each point $a ∈ X$ define the function $g_a$ by $g_a(x) = f_a(x)−f_c(x)$. Show that for any $a ∈ X$ the function $g_a$ is bounded.

(c) Show that for any $a, b ∈ X$,       $d_∞(g_a, g_b) = d(a, b)$ where $d_∞$ is the sup-metric on the space $B(X)$ of bounded functions on $X$.

Past paper question, but I don't have the solutions and don't know how to do it. I have done part (c). For a) how am I supposed to prove it if I don't know what the metric d is?
I have $\sup_{x∈X}|f_a(x) − f_b(x)| = \sup_{x∈X}|d(x,a) − d(x,b)|$, but how can I say this is equal to $d(a,b)$ without the definition of d?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just try the triangle inequality with $a,b,x$. It won't solve itself, you need to do some work.

Comment: How can I use the triangle inequality for (a)? or do you mean for part (b)?

Comment: Can you show that it achieves $d(a,b)$? Then what does the triangle inequality say about a third point $c$.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html

Comment: The part I'm struggling with the most is how to show that it achieved d(a,b) in part (a), if you read the last part of the question I explained why

Comment: What happens if you plug $a$ in, or $b$?

Comment: For a) how am I supposed to prove it if I don't know what the metric $d$ is? I have $\sup_{x∈X}|fa(x)−fb(x)|=\sup_{x∈X}|d(x,a)−d(x,b)|$, but how can I say this is equal to $d(a,b)$ without the definition of $d$ or assuming that it is the euclidean metric?

Comment: What is $d(a,a)$?

Comment: $d(a,a)=0$ since d is a metric

Comment: Ok so if I choose $x=a$, what is the value of the expression $f_a(x) - f_b(x)$?

Comment: Then it is $-d(a,b)$

Comment: Great, but we have absolute values, so you've shown that $sup_{x \in X} | f_a(x) - f_b(x)|$ achieves the value $d(a,b)$. (at both $a$ and $b$). What remains to show is that for any other $c$ in $x$, you can bound it above by this value.

Comment: Ok, but then I am saying that it is only true for $x=a$ right? Is this a valid proof?

Comment: You have shown that $d(a,b)$ is achieved, and so $d(a,b) \leq sup_{x\in X} |f_a(x) - f_b(x)|$. To show that it equals that supremum, you need to show that for any other value $c \in X$, $|f_a(c) - f_b(c)| \leq d(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know how I should approach part (b)

Comment: Think about how you might be able to use part (a)